# Does Sculpting create any new Geometry?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, geometry

I am going to use some sculpting to give a better shape to a Game Character, so I would like to know if Sculpting may add more geometry, for an instance the F layer brush or the F blob brush.

[image]

Comment: Not unless you are using dynamic topology when sculpting: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Dynamic_Topology_Sculpting

Comment: Sorry, but Sculpting only moves existing vertices and faces around, but does not create new geometry. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally sculpting does *not* add any vertices or edges, it just moves them around. But when you enable the `dynamic topology` option in the left toolbar `T` of your 3d view it adds vertices depending on the given value and your zoom level.

You wrote that you want to create a game character? I recommend that you copy your existing object and add more and more details. Then you can bake the normals and save a lot of memory and rendering time.

Comment: Where is this option in the left toolbar now?

Edit: It's on the upper-right of the view port now. A Checkbox for `Dyntopo`