# Why am I getting different shading on different faces when I merge the vertices?

Tags: mesh, topology

I started with a bowl shaped geometry with no top and no bottom.

I wanted to add geometry to the top of this semi-sphere, so that I can use sculpting to mould it to a desired state. [Does Sculpting create any new Geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36583/does-sculpting-create-any-new-geometry).

[image: my current state with no vertices on intersecting edges]

On bottom side I followed [How can I add vertices to intersection of two edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges) to add geometry and on the top side I extruded the vertices and merged them to the centre. [image: bottom side]

[image: top portion which is highlighted with a whitish color]

[image: my weird revelation]

Comment: Hello :). Aren't there by any chance some flipped faces? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/78972

Comment: I checked my face orientations. Not the problem.

Comment: Okay :). Since I'm not good at guessing, would you mind [sharing your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: I applied subsurf modifier and it tamed the problem for now. If something pops up in the future I'll surely get back to you. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you have inverted normals. In order to 'repair' the object, follow those steps:

1. Enter Edit Mode by pressing Tab.
2. Select every vertex in the model. You can press 1, then a (maybe even times).
3. Press Shift+N to recalculate normals outside, or Shift+Ctrl+N to recalculate inside.
4. Exit from Edit Mode by pressing Tab.

Those steps should help, but if you have messed up something other than normals, it may not help. You can also enable "Face orientation" in overlays menu in 3d Viewport to see blue/red faces indicating normals.

Comment: I checked my face orientations. Not the problem.

Comment: Maybe there is no problem at all. I carefully looked at your last picture. It seems that there ARE actually faces, but they are in shadow. What will happen when you rotate your object or change a matcap which is used to display it?